# How to use nested suspend in Kotlin android

Tags: android, kotlin

**I have this function in Kotlin:**

```
class DictionaryWorker constructor(
    context: Context,
    private val workerParameters: WorkerParameters,
    private val apiInterface: ApiInterface
) :
    KneuraWorker(context, workerParameters), BaseDataSource {

    private var isJobSuccess: Boolean = false

    override suspend fun doWorkerJob(): Result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {


        val call = apiInterface.downloadDictionaryFille(DICTIONARY_FILE_URL)

        call!!.enqueue(object : Callback<ResponseBody?> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<ResponseBody?>?,
                response: Response<ResponseBody?>
            ) {

                if (response.isSuccessful) {

                } else {
                    Log.d("TAG", "server contact failed")
                    isJobSuccess = false
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseBody?>?, t: Throwable?) { }

        })


        return@withContext if (isJobSuccess)
            Result.success()
        else
            Result.failure()
    }



}
```

---

**What is currently happening**:

*Before this `block-1` below*

```
call!!.enqueue(object : Callback<ResponseBody?> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<ResponseBody?>?,
                response: Response<ResponseBody?>
            ) {

                if (response.isSuccessful) {

                } else {
                    Log.d("TAG", "server contact failed")
                    isJobSuccess = false
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseBody?>?, t: Throwable?) { }

        })
```

*This `block-2` executes*

```
return@withContext if (isJobSuccess)
            Result.success()
        else
            Result.failure()
```

---

### *What I am trying to do*

*Make sure only after `block 1` is executed `block 2` is executed*

Comment: I don't use Retrofit, but there are coroutine ways to make these calls without having to use callbacks. Your code doesn't work because your block2 is not inside the callback. To make a callback interface work like a coroutine, you can use `suspendCancellableCoroutine`, but that's unnecessary in this case because Retrofit already has coroutine support built in, and if you use it, you won't need to use callbacks at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what call!!.enqueue() does, but it's quite likely that it starts another thread and performs it's work asynchronously.

So `block 2` is not waiting till `block 1` is done.

A really ugly way (which I don't recommend) handling this would be using a CountDownLatch.

But I'd rather add a callback to doWorkerJob():

```
override fun doWorkerJob(callback: (Result) -> Unit) {


        val call = apiInterface.downloadDictionaryFille(DICTIONARY_FILE_URL)

        if (call == null) {
           callback(Result.failure())
        }

        call?.enqueue(object : Callback<ResponseBody?> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<ResponseBody?>?,
                response: Response<ResponseBody?>
            ) {

                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                   callback(Result.success())
                } else {
                    Log.d("TAG", "server contact failed")
                    callback(Result.failure())
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseBody?>?, t: Throwable?) {
                callback(Result.failure())
            }

        })

    }
```